# Positioning an Excel display using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA in Excel 2013. I would like to position the active worksheet with a specific cell (eg "X25") in the upper left corner.  I have tried selecting cells off the currently displayed area, .Select ("ZZ200"), and then reselecting my target cell. I don't seem to be able to control where the target cell is positioned. Suggestions

Comment: Welcome to SO! [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Post what you've got for more help.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
Application.Goto Range("X25"), Scroll:=True
```

This article has more information and options that you might find helpful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839232.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I actually got most of this code using the "record macro" feature. it's a pretty handy tool when you don't know how to do something

```
my_cell = "ZZ2200"  'change this to whatever you need
cell_row = Range(my_cell).Row
cell_col = Range(my_cell).Column

'moves to the top left corner
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-9999
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Up:=-99999

'moves to your active cell
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = cell_row
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = cell_col

'selects your cell
Range(my_cell).Select
```