# How to end VBA on a specific sheet column?

Tags: excel, vba

After a macro has run I want the screen to be on a specific column of the spreadsheet so I can check the data has gone in correctly.

I worked out how to activate a specific sheet.

I tried this

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Column, "BW").Activate
```

It selects the first row of the column but doesn't move the screen to display the selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Application.Goto Range("A:A"), Scroll:=True
```

Change "A:A" to the desired columns.

Thanks to Lumigraphics answer
[Positioning an Excel display using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307782/positioning-an-excel-display-using-vba)

Comment: doesnt work. just selects the column but doesn't move the screen to the selected column

Comment: Can you try Application.Goto Range("A:A")

Comment: does the same as above unfortunately

Comment: One last try. This time:  Application.Goto Range("A:A"), Scroll:=True

Comment: One last try. This time:  Application.Goto Range("A:A"), Scroll:=True

Comment: Welcome and Done. I also added my source.

Answer (score 1):

"But it just selects the first row of the column and *doesn't move the screen to display the selection...*"

**Selects the first column of the target range, centering on the range. Doesn't handle frozen panes.**

*In a module*

```
Public Sub SelectColumnAndViewActive(cellrange As Range)
  Dim cellrangerow As Long
    cellrangerow = cellrange.Row
    cellrange.EntireColumn.Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll WorksheetFunction.Max(cellrangerow - 1 - Int(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Rows.Count / 2)), 0, 0, 0
End Sub
```

*Usage*

```
Call SelectColumnAndViewActive(ActiveCell)
```

*Explanation*

We first store the row number of the active cell, because it will be lost after selecting a column. Then we select the active cell's first column. The latter will automatically put the first row of the sheet at the top of the active window, so we need to scroll a certain number of rows to center on what was originally the active cell in the last step.

**Selects only the target range, centering on it. Does handle frozen panes and discontinuous ranges.**

*In a module*

```
Public Sub CenterRange(cellrange As Range)
  Dim cellitems() As String, tlrcitems() As String, brrcitems() As String, minrow As Long, mincol As Long, maxrow As Long, maxcol As Long
    If cellrange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each area In cellrange.Areas
        cellitems = Split(area.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), ":")
        tlrcitems = Split(Mid$(cellitems(0), 2), "C")
        If UBound(cellitems) = 1 Then brrcitems = Split(Mid$(cellitems(1), 2), "C") Else brrcitems = tlrcitems
        If minrow = 0 Then minrow = tlrcitems(0) Else minrow = WorksheetFunction.Min(minrow, CLng(tlrcitems(0)))
        If mincol = 0 Then mincol = tlrcitems(1) Else mincol = WorksheetFunction.Min(mincol, CLng(tlrcitems(1)))
        If maxrow = 0 Then maxrow = brrcitems(0) Else maxrow = WorksheetFunction.Max(maxrow, CLng(brrcitems(0)))
        If maxcol = 0 Then maxcol = brrcitems(1) Else maxcol = WorksheetFunction.Max(maxcol, CLng(brrcitems(1)))
    Next
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(minrow - (ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Rows.Count - (maxrow - minrow + 1)) \ 2, 1)
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = WorksheetFunction.Max(mincol - (ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Columns.Count - (maxcol - mincol + 1)) \ 2, 1)
    cellrange.Select
End Sub
```

*Usage*

```
Call CenterRange(ActiveCell)
```

*Explanation*

First, we discarding empty target ranges. We then iterate through all the areas of the discontinuous target range, get their addresses in R1C1 format (e.g. R5C3 for row 5 and column 3) in order to find the minimum and the maximum "boundaries" of the entire range. Finally, we center on the range by setting the values of the first row and the first column of the active window to calculated values, followed by selecting the target range.

---

You're probably interested in the first part of the answer. You can, of course, replace `ActiveCell` with any other range you like when calling the subs.

EDIT: I was writing this when you accepted the answer. I decided to post it anyway, as it also centers on the row in question after selecting the column, and there's also a part that might interest you if by any chance your range is discontinuous. And yes, I tried `Application.GoTo` as well when I had this very issue, and quickly noticed its limitations.

Comment: appreciate the in depth answer. above and beyond

Comment: And I appreciate the upvote ;) Maybe someone else might need it someday.